# How to call a webservice continuously in every seconds?

Tags: android, web-services

```
allVehiclesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                String item=allVehiclesSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                if(!item.equalsIgnoreCase("Select")){
                    position=0;

                    vdetails.vehicleNo = item;
                    dbhHelper.opendatabase();
                    vdetails=dbhHelper.getVehicleId(item);
                    dbhHelper.close();




                    getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask livetask=new getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask();                 
                    livetask.execute();                     

                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

public class getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(VTS_LiveTracking.this);
        Dialog.setMessage(VTS_LiveTracking.this.getResources().getString(
                R.string.loading));
        Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        Dialog.show();
        Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result="";
        Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "AsyncTask>>>>>>>>>>>");
        if(isInternetPresent){
            try {
                Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "AsyncTask CHeck Internet>>>>>>>>>>>");
                Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "VehicleId CHeck Internet>>>>>>>>>>>"+vdetails.vehicleId);

                vd=WebServiceHelper.getLiveTrackingDetails(ClientCode, SecretCode, vdetails.vehicleId);
                //vd=WebServiceHelper.getLiveTrackingDetails(ClientCode, SecretCode, "2");  

                Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "VD>>>>>>>>"+vd.length);
                for(int i=0;i<vd.length;i++){

                    Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "LiveTrackingElements1>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+vd[i].deviceMobNo);
                    Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "LiveTrackingElements2>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+vd[i].driverName);
                    vdetails.latitude=vd[i].latitude;
                    vdetails.longitude=vd[i].longitude;

                    Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "vdetails.latitudeLiveTrackingElements1>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+vdetails.latitude);
                    Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "vdetails.longitudeLiveTrackingElements2>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+vdetails.longitude);



                }


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result="Success";
        }else{              
            result="Failure";
}
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.contentEquals("Success")){
            Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "AsyncTaskonPostExecute>>>>>>>>>>>");
            Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "statuslogin>>>>>>>>>>>"+vdetails.status_login);
            if(vdetails.status_login.equals("success")){

                String lat=vdetails.latitude;
                String lon=vdetails.longitude;
                latitude=Double.parseDouble(vdetails.latitude);
                longitude=Double.parseDouble(vdetails.longitude);
                Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "latitude>>>>"+vdetails.latitude);
                Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG,"longitude>>>>"+vdetails.longitude);
                latlng=new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                 Marker m=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15.0f));


                    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(VTS_LiveTracking.this);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                            dialog.setTitle("Report");

                            TextView driver, speed,latitude,longitude,last_updated_time,gps_status,
                             driver_mobile_no,vehicle_idle_status,ac_status,device_mobile_no,engine_status;

                            driver = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.drivernametxt);
                        speed=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.speedvaluetxt);
                            latitude=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.latitudetxt);
                            longitude=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.longitudetxt);
                            last_updated_time=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.last_updated_timetxt);
                            gps_status=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.gps_statustxt);
                            driver_mobile_no=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.driver_mobile_notxt);
                            vehicle_idle_status=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_idle_statustxt);
                            ac_status=(TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.ac_statustxt);
                            device_mobile_no=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.device_mobile_notxt);
                            engine_status=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.engine_statustxt);

                            driver.setText(vdetails.driverName);
                        speed.setText(vdetails.vehicleSpeed);
                            latitude.setText(vdetails.latitude);
                            longitude.setText(vdetails.longitude);
                            last_updated_time.setText(vdetails.lastUpdatedDateTime);
                            gps_status.setText(vdetails.gpsStatus);
                            driver_mobile_no.setText(vdetails.driverMobNo);
                        vehicle_idle_status.setText(vdetails.vehicleIdleStatus);
                            ac_status.setText(vdetails.acStatus);
                            device_mobile_no.setText(vdetails.deviceMobNo);
                            engine_status.setText(vdetails.engineStatus);
                            dialog.show();

                            Button cancel=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);

                            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();                                   
                                }
                            });

                            return false;

                        }
                    });



            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vdetails.failReason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else if(result.contentEquals("Failure")){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Dialog.dismiss();
        Dialog=null;
    }

}
}
```

Hi,
    For my app,It is very necessary to display the location of a vehicle at a particular location.The location of the vehicle is given by the json webservices.Also the vehicle is moving and location is updated by the webservice.But according to my code the vehicle is not moving.How can I implement the movement of vehicle in my app?How can I implement the location change using timer?Is there any other methods to implement this?
    Please help me
    Here is my code

Answer (score 2):

Use `Timer`..

```
mytimer = new Timer();
final TimerTask mytask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       //your code here                     
}
});


mytimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, int delay, int time);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Class To Start Service**

```
allVehiclesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                String item=allVehiclesSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                if(!item.equalsIgnoreCase("Select")){
                    position=0;

                    vdetails.vehicleNo = item;
                    dbhHelper.opendatabase();
                    vdetails=dbhHelper.getVehicleId(item);
                    dbhHelper.close();

               Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,
                Service_A.class);
    startService(intent);

                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

**USE SERVICE TO UPDATE WEBSERVICE AFTER 1 SEC**

```
Service_ A extend service
{
private  Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         handler.postDelayed(Service_ A.this,1000);

    }
//do you code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use thread to invoke async task every second use below code to replace

```
 getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask livetask=new getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask();                 
 livetask.execute();    

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

         try {
         Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
         new getLiveTrackingsAsyncTask.execute();                 

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
         });

         thread.start();
```